# Unable to go to Second View after login with Touch ID or Face id - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have written the following code where after the user logs in with touch id or face id it should go to the next view controller.

```
@IBAction func logInButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {             
         context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Account") { (correct, error) in

                if correct {                   
                    print("Logged In....")

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondView", sender: self)                  
                } else {
                    print("Not Logged in....")
                }
            }

        } else {
            print("No Support for Biometrics")
        }
    }
```

I'm able to print the Logged in and Not Logged in message. But after user gets authenticated that is after Logged In message is printed I get the following message in console for "performSegue"

019-03-21 19:37:18.473350-0400 Login v1[7596:2446134] [Animation] +[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:] being called from a background thread. Performing any operation from a background thread on UIView or a subclass is not supported and may result in unexpected and insidious behavior. trace=(
    0   UIKitCore                           0x00000001d6ac7710  + 136
    1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010159cdc8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010159ee28 _dispatch_once_callout + 84

and much more. I have connected my second view controller and made is display as "Present Modally". not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message states, any operations that affect the UI must be performed on the main thread.

The callback from `context.evaluatePolicy` is being invoked on some other thread.

All you need to do is dispatch the `performSegue` on thee main thread:

```
@IBAction func logInButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {             
     context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Account") { (correct, error) in

            if correct {                   
                print("Logged In....")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondView", sender: self)               
                }   
            } else {
                print("Not Logged in....")
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("No Support for Biometrics")
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Got to know where I made a mistake. Thanks, @Paulw11